# Yii2 Advanced app, different session for frontend and backend with subdomains

Tags: session, authentication, yii2, frontend, backend

I have a problem with my Yii2 app.
I have a advanced-app with frontend and backend parts on different domains (subdomain). I use webvimark user management module, but I think the problem is not in it.

Frontend app -> domain.com
Backend app -> admin.domain.com

So I have problem with login in backend, it is not working.
I enter login and password, and after submit form I see login form again.

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name'     => '_backendIdentity',
            'domain'     => 'admin.domain.com',
        ],
        'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig',
    ],
```

and

```
'session' => [
        'name' => 'BACKENDSESSID',
        'cookieParams' => [
            'domain'     => 'admin.domain.com',
        ],
    ],
```

Any ideas?

**Update #1:** My config located: /backend/config/main.php
**Update #2:** There was a problem when transferring backend on a subdomain

Comment: maybe you need to add savePath param

Comment: Where is located the  configuration you show?

Comment: My config located: /backend/config/main.php

Comment: @nuriddin-rashidov It did not help

Comment: Are you checked out sessions in browser. is it  setted?

Comment: @nuriddin-rashidov yes, is setter as BACKENDSESSID with domain = .admin.domain.com, and path = /

Comment: can u post your behavior rules for backend controller

Comment: @nuriddin-rashidov I use a webvimark user management module, I dont have a login controller at backend/frontend, and in module AuthContoller dont have any behavior. Also, I forget to say, previusly without subdomains, configuration working okey, there was a problem when transferring backend on a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Okey, there was a problem with the configuration of the module, as well as the wrong config in the frontend.

**Backend:**

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_backendIdentity',
            'domain' => 'backend.test.dev',
        ],
        'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig',
        'on afterLogin' => function ($event) {
            \webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\UserVisitLog::newVisitor($event->identity->id);
        },
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'BACKENDSESSID',
        'cookieParams' => [
            'domain' => 'backend.test.dev',
        ],
    ],
```

**Frontend:**

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name'     => '_frontendIdentity',
            'path'     => '/',
        ],
        'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig',
        'on afterLogin' => function ($event) {
            \webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\UserVisitLog::newVisitor($event->identity->id);
        }
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'FRONTENDSESSID',
        'cookieParams' => [
            'path'     => '/',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to make codeception functional tests work for different subdomains?