# Login on advanced template with frontend and backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I have followed the instructions of [Yii2-user documentation](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/usage-with-advanced-template.md) using the advanced template, but can't be able to signup frontend users and backend users on the same server.

Investigating the structure of the table user and reading more about Yii2-user, I have not found a clear mechanism to recognize 2 different users as a frontend and backend one.

Only the admin can *CRUD* users, but that one too can only be mentioned in config by their username. Meaning they are recorded as other users.

Did anyone really use Yii2-user on advanced template with the frontend and backend residing on the same server?

Comment: Could you access to frontend and backend? Or you need to have different sessions? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425741/yii2-advanced-app-different-session-for-frontend-and-backend-with-subdomains

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I happened to use this and worked https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/issues/335